# detect new element in html using selenium, python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

is it possible to detect in selenium, that new dynamic element added in html

```
msg_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3u328')

    msg_box.send_keys('---')
    button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3M-N-')
    button.click()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know what element will be added you can use explicit wait with :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec

is_found = WebDriverWait(webdriver, time).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((by, locator)))
```

Small info on waits can be found [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can find (in a loop) all elements which match your condition with `find_elements_by_*` getting the list of elements and check if the list is changed. If yes - that would mean new element was added.

Comparing previous list and new one you will detect which element exactly.